# Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid on a for each statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, integer, type-conversion

As the title says, I'm getting an error from my code below, which basically selects multiple inputs on a `ListView`, and puts it inside a database. Here's the code:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
        Dim StudentID = Integer.Parse(item.SubItems(0).Text)
        Dim FirstName = item.SubItems(1).Text
        Dim LastName = item.SubItems(2).Text
            DBConn()
            SQLSTR = "INSERT INTO '" & TextBox4.Text & "' (StudentID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('" & StudentID & "', '" & FirstName & "', '" & LastName & "') "
            alterDB()
            MsgBox("Students succesfully added", msgboxtitle)
        Next
    MsgBox("Students added!", , msgboxtitle)
End Sub
```

The exact error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: I assume the error is on the line Dim StudentID = Integer.Parse(item.SubItems(0).Text)?  Can you step through to see what is the value of item.SubItems(0).Text when the error occurs?  Possibly there are some non numerical characters such as spaces

Comment: You should not build sql by concatenating string like this. This is prone to sql injection.

Comment: @user3479671 When I check the database, the first line in the list view gets in, but the other lines doesn't so I assume the error comes from the looping? If that makes sense

Comment: @im_a_noob is there a way to change it? I'm a beginner in coding and this is what I got from asking and formulating around.

Comment: regarding the sql injection thing, you'd have to pass the form values to a variable and validate them before including them in a sql string.  That aside, when you step through the program, put your mouse over item.SubItems(0).Text) when it errors, a tool tip should pop up to tell you its value

Comment: @MicoRigunay I see that the question is now tagged vb.net (I think it was VBA when I first commented). You have to use parameterized query. Here a link that should get your started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i With this link and google you should figure it out. If not simply another question here on SO

Comment: it is usually the job of the DB to assign IDs, so you should not be passing that at all.  In cases when you do pass it - eg in a SELECT or UPDATE - pass it as an int, not text.  This is best done with SQL Parameters

Comment: @MicoRigunay that explains the integer.parse.  I was wondering about that myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CInt()` to convert to Integer. [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx)

I'd recommend `Dim variable As Type` before you define the variable though.

```
    Dim item As ListViewItem        
    Dim StudentID as Integer
    Dim FirstName as String
    Dim LastName as String

    For Each item In ListView1.SelectedItems
        StudentID = CInt(item.SubItems(0).Text)
        FirstName = item.SubItems(1).Text
        LastName = item.SubItems(2).Text
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error though. It's weird because the first line on my ListView gets in the database, but the next lines do not.

Comment: @Chrismas007 the OP would also have to get rid of the ticks around `StudentID` that would pass the Int as text to the db layer

Comment: @MicoRigunay just out of curiosity, does the database require that the StudentID be numeric?  It seems odd considering it's name

Comment: @Chrismas007 never mind, got it to work. I removed the MsgBox on the loop and it got fixed. Thanks!